# Webots supervisor simulation Reset Physics error

Tags: nodes, collision, webots

I am using webots R2021b,when i run my program,i found error of Webots supervisor simulation Reset Physics error- "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'simulationResetPhysics.

How i can solve this error,which causes that collision devices are not found.